# Shape of shielding for a tidally-stabilized LEO space station

Tags: low-earth-orbit, space-station, shielding

Let's say that we're going to seriously shield a manned space station (to the tune of 1-2 m thickness) in LEO so that radiation doses are a reasonable multiple of background on Earth. Let's also assume that we have freedom of attitude selection, so we can have one direction constantly pointing toward the Earth.

Could you omit the Earth-facing wall because cosmic rays won't come from below? Or maybe the radiation will scatter back up? What would an optimized shielding envelope look like?

Comment: This should probably be discussed by whomever answers the question. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terrestrial_gamma-ray_flash

Comment: It's my understanding ions in the Van Allen Belt spiral from one magnetic pole to the other. I've always imagined an ion's path to look like a loxodrome and the flight path angle to be nearly zero. It's this is the case, you could concentrate protection along the sides with less on the floor pointing towards earth. For high energy GCRs I'd expect the earth's influence wouldn't bend their path much so not many would go deep into earth's "shadow".

Comment: I think you're most worried about GCRs striking atoms in earth's upper atmosphere and sending some of the fragments upwards. For this radiation source I would expect a flux similar to the ISS. Lower, if the manned station is at a higher altitude.

Comment: Answering this will require quite a bit of reading. For the time being, I'll dump a few most relevant links I found: http://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/1043.html (follow "Results Publications" section), http://www.dsls.usra.edu/meetings/radiation2003/pdf/3012Wilson.pdf, http://www.wrmiss.org/workshops/seventeenth/El-Jaby.pdf, http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20060051805.pdf, http://www.ann-geophys.net/23/2983/2005/angeo-23-2983-2005.pdf, https://workspace.imperial.ac.uk/highenergyphysics/Public/theses/Mitchelll.pdf (good problem overview)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I'd completely eliminate the Earth facing board, but I would reduce the shielding. The shielding should be stronger for the side pointing away from Earth, and be reduced as one gets to a side closer to Earth. Basically, this is a geometry problem. You can still hit the spacecraft from the sides of the Earth, even though cosmic rays will not be transmitted through the Earth itself. Thus, for any position not on the surface of a body, there is still a chance of some radiation coming through. The closer to Earth, the less radiation would spill through.

However, it's worth noting that Earth's magnetic field does a pretty reasonable job at removing such radiation. They also move the direction somewhat differently. In some cases, they might even come in from below (Although I'd have to actually do the math, which I am not at the moment). Still, I suspect more shielding would be needed on the sides, and less the side pointed directly to Earth and directly away from Earth, due to the magnetic field.